# Magento 1.9 Category wise shipping charges

Tags: magento-1.9, category, shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

For my Magento 1.9 website I want to set a **feature to add specific Flat rate postage and packaging for categories**.

I have check in the Magento backend  but there is `flat table rates` setting available only for weight, price, no. of items against destinations.

I have also googled and check in Magento marketplace but I didn’t find any solution/extension to set `category wise shipping rate`.

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this functionality. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use thi shipping per product instead of category

Comment: @JigsParmar Yes I have checked that also but we want category wise only

Comment: you can use that extension and customized that based on category

Comment: @JigsParmar I have search for extensions but I didn't find any solution which is match with my requirement.